# Use python to modify words in a LaTex file, ignoring LaTeX markup

Tags: python, latex

I want to run an automated "spell checker" over some LaTex files (in addition to spelling it detects certain custom words, etc). I need to read the LaTex file, find certain words in the document text (i.e. ignoring words if they are part of the LaTeX markup code), then wrap each word in additional LaTeX highlighting markup and write the file back out. E.g.

```
\title{My Document}
...
I won the title!
```

If I search for "title", then it should ignore "\title".

This is so that, when rendered, the modified LaTeX will display found words using the highlighting I add e.g.:

```
\title{My Document}
...
I won the \colorbox{red}{title}!
```

A library would be helpful since I may eventually require additional parsing/control features, but simple modification is all I need for now.

It seems the hard part is discerning LaTex commands, comments, etc. from actual body text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Python LaTeX parser to do this.  This looks like a good candidate https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup, there there are several available.

Like BeautifulSoup, there are search functions which would allow you to find all text nodes, then you can use regular python split/search functions to find your misspelled words, then replace the text node with a new set of latex nodes (with the wrapping syntax around the selected words).

TexSoup's documentation is a little unclear as to how to write the document back out, but looking at their source code they appear to override the `repr` function, so:

```
with open('out.tex','w') as f:
  f.write(repr(soup))
```

Should do it for you.

**EDIT:**

If you look at the `descendants` generator:

```
>>> [x for x in soup.descendants if isinstance(x, str)]
['\x08egin', '(n.) A sacred fruit. Also known as:', '\x08egin', 'Here is the prevalence of each synonym.', '\x08egin', 'red lemon & uncommon ', 'Hello \textit', '.', 'Watermelon', 'red lemon', 'life', 'itemize', '& common', 'tabular', 'document']
```

The "children" are a mix of `str`s and `TexNode`s.  You can pick out the pure strings there for your check, and just walk the tree yourself.  The `children` attribute bizzarely only includes the `TextNode` elements.

Comment: Thanks - I have TexSoup (as part of Latex2Python). Do you know how I can "find all text nodes"? The documentation is light, definitely. I probably need to check "text" in things like section headings too.

Comment: thanks for the accept.  been looking at the TextSoup code.  you're right, their docs suck.  hold on, edit coming...

Comment: Thanks for investigating!! I have a recursive piece of code that kind of does this, but when I modify the str values they're not updated in the source "soup" object. Bah! Must be doing something wrong!

Comment: strings are immutable, so changing them will have no effect, as the original is still in the tree.  it looks like to change the doc, you need to use the `expr` attribute, which is an `TexExpr`, which has a `soup.expr._contents` attr, which is a list that you can do regular list operations on, like replacing a string w/ another.

Comment: author of TexSoup here, sorry for the lack of docs. Instead of modifying the private variable `_contents`, the soup/node object exposes a few in-place modification functions: Say you identify `oldString` and modify the string to get `newString`. You can add the `newString` using `soup.replace_child(oldString, newString)` for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I got what you need, the python shouldn't be the best fitting instrument. I think that the thing what you need is `sed` or `vim` editors and a group of editing scripts. It'd work faster and be easier to maintain than writing python script

Comment: I think the hardest part is discerning LaTex text from body text. Simple search and replace is very easy, certainly.

Comment: Well, looking at your example
> f I search for "title", then it should ignore "\title".
It'd be easy in `vim` using leading characters

Comment: I just don't know the sed regex syntax, but I presume it mostly similar.

You can do it in `vim` using such regex `%s/[^\\]\zstitle/goooo/g`. `goooo` is here just for example, you can replace it with what you want

Comment: Hi Alex - I modified the question a little since I didn't mention this needs to be an automatic process, happening as part of other workflow operations.

Comment: Well, this can be easily done, if you are using `vim`, but with sed there are several issues in implementation. In python it'd be a bit harder, because you will have to run more regexes for discerning the latex syntax, or to run more checkings than you need. So I strongly recommend to add `vim` into your workflow :-)